# How to to decompile a pyinstaller exe, back to source code?

Tags: python, disassemblers

Python versions, this method has been tried on: 3.7.5, 3.6.0, 3.5.0, 2.7.17? (I know, I'm just too desperate to get my source back.)

I have problem with decompiling an exe. I kind of deleted the wrong folder and now I'm left with the `.exe`, made by pyinstaller and nothing else. So basically I googled how to `decompile pyinstaller exes` and I found that first I use this: https://github.com/countercept/python-exe-unpacker/blob/master/pyinstxtractor.py to dissasemble to `.pyc` files and then `uncompyle6` to get the source. The problem is that `pyinstxtractor` doesn't return the source code in `.pyc` format so I basically had to convert it myself and then add the "magic numbers" to it so that `uncompyle6` sees it as `.pyc`. If you are wondering how I got the magic numbers, well I just used a hex editor to see the magic numbers of another `.pyc`, that `pyinstxtractor` spat out and then I just pasted them in the main file. So after that, I write

```
uncompyle63 name_of_pyc.pyc
```

and I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python\lib\site-packages\xdis\load.py", line 208, in load_module_from_file_object
    co = marshal.loads(bytecode)
ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python\lib\site-packages\xdis\load.py", line 208, in load_module_from_file_object
    co = marshal.loads(bytecode)
ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\python\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Python\Scripts\uncompyle6.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "c:\python\lib\site-packages\uncompyle6\bin\uncompile.py", line 194, in main_bin
    **options)
  File "c:\python\lib\site-packages\uncompyle6\main.py", line 261, in main
    source_encoding, linemap_stream, do_fragments)
  File "c:\python\lib\site-packages\uncompyle6\main.py", line 161, in decompile_file
    source_size) = load_module(filename, code_objects)
  File "c:\python\lib\site-packages\xdis\load.py", line 116, in load_module
    get_code=get_code,
  File "c:\python\lib\site-packages\xdis\load.py", line 222, in load_module_from_file_object
    "Ill-formed bytecode file %s\n%s; %s" % (filename, kind, msg)
ImportError: Ill-formed bytecode file Bot.pyc
<class 'ValueError'>; bad marshal data (unknown type code)
```

What are some other ways to decompile pyinstaller executables (If this one is useless)?

Comment: before attempting to go the hard way  have you looked around and tried  some of the recovery software like undelete  etc  basically file deletion just erases  the file details not the file contents and many software exist which can recover the deleted files

Comment: I'd guess it's to late once you started tinkering ... at the point such a mistake is made and you want to use an undelete tool you basically need to "pull the plug". Each additional write diminishes your chances to recover some of the deleted data.

Answer (score 2):

As you said, `.pyc` files begin with a magic (per python version)+timestamp.
The tools sometimes fail reading these files despite them being correctly structured.
Anyhow, this metadata is not required for decompiling.

If you can get to the beginning of the marshal'd code, usually at offset 8 from the beginning of the `.pyc` file, you can use python's built-in `dis` and `marshal` libraries:

```
import dis
import marshal
f = open("file.pyc","rb")
f.seek(8) #assuming there are magic numbers at the beginning
code = marshal.load(f)
dis.dis(code)
```

Inconveniently, it prints the code to `stdout` instead of returning it as text to the caller.

Make sure you run the code from the python version that the `.pyc` is originally compiled for.